# How to empty an Observable with delete - Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to delete everything from an observable but it doesn't work :

This is what I did so far in my service:

```
    deleteAllHistory(Histories$:Observable<History[]>){
    Histories$.forEach((history)=>{this.deleteHistory(history.id)})
  }
```

I trigger this function when I click on a button in my component. This is the function that handles deletion in my component .ts :

```
Histories$=this.facade.Histories$;

histo:History[];

this.Histories$.subscribe(history => {
        this.histo = history as History[];
        
    })

onDeleteAll(){
        this.historyService.deleteAllHistory(this.histo);
      }
```

But it does not delete anything, I guess because I have to delete from the Observable : Histories$.

Thank you for your time !

As requested, the post call :

```
addHistory(history:History){
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL, history);
  }
```

This is par of the template :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="Histories$ | async">
                <ng-container
                  *ngFor="let group of Histories$ | async | groupByDay"
                >
                  <strong>{{ group[0] | date:'longDate'}}</strong>
                  <br />
                  <br />
              
                  <div *ngFor="let history of group[1]">
            <mat-list-item  class="historyClicking" (mouseover)="history.showTrash=true" (mouseout)="history.showTrash=false" (click)="onclick()">

                
                <div class="block">
                     
                <div matList>{{history.SNS}}</div>
                <div matList>{{history.title}}</div>
                <div matList>{{history.DMC}}</div>
```

Comment: First problem you are not returning an observable in this.historyService.deleteAllHistory function. The second problem it the approach to delete all the history take a look if exist an API to pass ids range or verify if an endpoint delete all the history by it self. Third you will need to subscribe the service function when it returns an observable

Comment: OK so I have to return an Observable in my service, and I have to subscribe to the service function. Could you share some code if it's not too much to ask ? It'll be of great help

Answer (score -1):

For the http request to run you need to subscribe to the observable.
Here is how I would do it using [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

```
deleteAllHistory(histories: History[]){
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    ...histories.map(history => this.http.delete(`${this.apiURL}/${history.id}`)
  );
}

onDeleteAll(){
  this.historyService
      .deleteAllHistory(this.histo)
      .subscribe(() => console.log('Deleted all'));
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could take an Observable as a parameter and then delete everything in it like in my deleteAllHistory function ( I changed the code in the question to show you). D o you think it's possible that way ?

Comment: where is the post call ?

Comment: I have just added the post call to my question

Comment: No, I think Just follow my answer and the answer from norbert-bartko. as an additional improvement you can create an endpoint to delete an ids range or literally all the history.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work because I forgot to mention that in my template I am using the Observable : Histories$ not the array : histo. So basically I am deleting something that I am not even using in my template

Comment: I added a template screenshot

Comment: Honestly I get more and more confused by your code snippets in your question. For example your are using `Histories$ | async` twice in your template, what will call your endpoint twice, aditionaly you store the result in your class. Would it be possible to create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgfn79?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to clean things up?